# TV white space software

Tags: networking, wifi, radio

I heard the TV white space (Radio) is unallocated frequency given to broadcasting services. been reading about the superwifi using this frequency and thought how one can use it for personal use.

**My question is**, assuming I have a legal license and necessary hardware(transmitters/receivers) and i wanted to send data from one computer to another (TCP/IP server to server) using white space which software can i use to receive/transmit the data?

Answer (score 1):

To make use of **any** given part of the electromagnetic spectrum you have to have **hardware** that makes use of that part of the spectrum.

To do so **legally** you also need to a licence to use that part of the spectrum for that purpose.

Providing the hardware & its drivers provides a TCP/IP implementation then you simply just make use of the network protocols.  Which specific programs &/or protocols you use depends on the type of data and the constraints: this can be file transfer with TFP/TFPT/SFTP, streaming, etc.

Comment: I made some edits, assuming I have a legal license and all hardware in place, transmitters and receivers. what software solutions can I look into.

Comment: @Tuna the point is that the __hardware__ uses the white space the software doesn't even know about it - it is exactly the same as any other network connection.

Comment: so that means the software is sort of bundled with the hardware(transmitters/receivers) ?

Comment: NO it means that the software is not concerned or aware of HOW it packets of data get where they are going just that they get there - one of the joys of tcp/ip (in fact THE point) is that some of the packets in a given transfer my travel a completely different route, over different hardware, to the others. The drivers, bundled with the hardware or OS, know what controls the hardware has but the software to do the send & receive doesn't know or need to know what hardware is involved let alone which bit of the spectrum it is using.